# Can a one process and another process which is having a multiple threads can synchronise with one shared resource

Tags: c, linux

i have one process which is using a shared resource and one process which is having a multiple threads but this process is also using a same shared resource i want to know can these multiple threads in one process and another process can synchronise for the same shared resource in linux?"

```
    fi1e1.c
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<pthread.h>
    #include<sys/types.h>
    #include<sys/stat.h>
    #include<unistd.h>
    #include<fcntl.h>
    #include<semaphore.h>
    sem_t *sem;
    void * call_processing(void*p){
        printf(" tid %u\n",pthread_self());

        while(1){
            sem_wait(sem);
            printf("shivInside sem tid %u \n",pthread_self());
            //  sleep(2);
            while(1);
            sem_post(sem);
            printf("shivAfter sem tid %u \n",pthread_self());
        }
    }
    void * call_processing1(void*p){
        printf(" tid %u\n",pthread_self());

        while(1){
            sem_wait(sem);
            printf("Inside sem tid %u  \n",pthread_self());
            sleep(5);
            sem_post(sem);
        }
    }

    main(int argc ,char **argv){

        pthread_t tid,tid1;
        sem = sem_open( argv[1], O_CREAT, 0666,  1);
        printf("sem=%d\n",sem);
        if ( sem < 0)
        {
            perror("sem_open: ");
            exit(1);
        }


        if (pthread_create(&tid, NULL, &call_processing, NULL) != 0) {
            printf ("Unable to create the Call processing thread \n");
        }


        if (pthread_create(&tid1, NULL, &call_processing1, NULL) != 0) {
            printf ("Unable to create the Call processing thread \n");
        }

        while(1);
    }
    ======================================================================
    File 2.c
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<semaphore.h>

    sem_t *sem;


    main(int argc ,char **argv){


        sem = sem_open(argv[1],1);
        if(sem<0){
            perror("sem_init");
        }
        sem_wait(sem);
        printf("hi\n");
        sem_post(sem);

}
```

Comment: Yes it probably can.

Comment: What code have you written so far? Where exactly does the problem occur?

Comment: @iwin :how can we do that?

Comment: @underscore_d : i am just trying the to synchronise the shared data between two process and in that one process is having a multiple threads that should synchronise the same shared resource

Answer (score 0):

Of course they can. But beware - if you terminate the `fi1e1` process when the value of the semaphore is currently zero (which likely is, due to the endless `while(1);` loop after the `sem_wait(sem);`), the value will still be zero from the next start of `fi1e1` on (the `sem_open( argv[1], O_CREAT, 0666,  1)` only sets the *initial value* for a *new semaphore*) and so the program's second run will behave differently from the first run. You could delete the semaphore by removing its virtual file system name `/dev/shm/sem.…`.